# What to do if the asker of a question doesn’t accept a correct answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

This is something that has happened to me multiple times. Here’s what’s been going on

1. I find a question that hasn’t been active for some time, say a few months
2. I post a high quality answer that includes code, tells why it works, points out errors in original code, and actually answers the question
3. I wait, hoping that they will either provide feedback on why my solution didn’t work or accept the answer if it did work
4. Nothing happens. The user doesn’t respond at all.

How should I alert the asker to the answer without violating the terms of service or being rude?

Keep in mind, I’m not trying to get reputation. The point of asking a question is to get an answer that deserves to be accepted.

Comment: patience, is about all you can do about it. It'd be difficult to leave a comment asking them to take notice of it without it looking like you're asking for rep. they will already receive a notification of the answer when you answer it, so leaving a comment is redundant.

Comment: If it is any comfort, the main goal of this site isn't necessarily to help the person asking the question but to provide future visitors who are googling for problems with an answer. If you keep providing quality answers the results will come with time as long as the searchbot indexing gods are good. It doesn't really matter if the answer has that green checkmark or not.

Comment: To expand slightly on @ivarni's comment - if you would like your answer to be recognised by visitors besides the OP, consider whether the _question_ needs to be edited to make it more search-friendly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How should I alert the asker to the answer without violating the terms of service or being rude?

You don't.
While you are being a good citizen in providing high quality answers to older or unloved questions, there is absolutely no onus on the asker ("OP") to accept an answer. We would like them to, but it isn't (and arguably never has been) a requirement.

I feel your pain, I have a number of these myself. But consider these possibilities:

- the OP doesn't visit frequently (or ever)
- they're not an experienced user
- they don't have the same level of desire to square things away and "do the right thing" by up voting and/or marking answers

No matter how frustrated you feel you should avoid attempting to get the attention of the OP in order to get a vote or an answer mark - that sort of activity is prevalent in forum style sites and isn't favored here.

Do keep up your good work, don't let the apathy of the OP or general lack of feedback get to you.

Comment: Most of my answers are on questions posted by users who created an account, asked the question, and never came back. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AlexH don't worry about the person who wrote the question, worry about everyone else that will read your answer. Answer acceptance is icing on the cake, not a goal.

Comment: @AlexH you should pay more attention to "viewed" count on the question and "last seen" on OP account - it should be a good indication is anyone will ever at least see your work... Question with "viewed" count under let's say 50 and OP is gone is not a useful place to provide high quality answer (unless you want to practice something) as most likely noone will ever see it.